# How to set a character set per application in *nix?

Tags: linux, slackware, charset

I am attempting to set a character set of IBM850 on slackware linux for a particular application (epic5).

Im using rxvt-unicode and have setup LANG/LC_*=en_US. Now if I set the encoding to IBM850 in kde's konsole program im able to display certain characters correctly. I'd rather not use IBM850 for everything; is there a way to set/alias a command for a per application execution?

Ive tried things like:

```
LC_CTYPE=IBM850 epic5
LC_ALL=IBM850 epic5
```

No success. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That notation for specifying environment variables is only understood by shells. In order to use it without a shell you need to use `env`.

```
env LC_ALL=en_US.IBM850 epic5
```

Comment: Ive tried the above with no luck; rxvt-unicode requires to be in the same encoding as the application. With this I tried "env LC_CTYPE=IBM850 urxvt -e epic5" with no success.